# How can I fix a RestDocumentationGenerationException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /curl-request.adoc (Read-only file system) in my Spring Boot app?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-restdocs

Would you believe googling this returned a whopping two results!

I'm trying to use Spring REST Docs (`spring-restdocs-mockmvc`) to generate API documentation for my service.

Running on a macbook pro with M2 processor.
I've read that this issue happens because `/` is the root directory on a mac, and that is read only.
I don't know why that path is being used though.
I have the system property `org.springframework.restdocs.outputDir` set, and when I check it the path is correct: `/Users/me/workspace/my-service/target/generated-snippets`.

My code looks like this:

```java
@SpringBootTest()
@ExtendWith(RestDocumentationExtension.class)
class ExampleControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp(RestDocumentationContextProvider restDocumentation) {
        System.out.println("Output Directory: " + System.getProperty("org.springframework.restdocs.outputDir"));
        this.mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context)
                                      .apply(MockMvcRestDocumentation.documentationConfiguration(restDocumentation))
                                      .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void index() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
           .andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(content().string(containsString("\"name\":\"Example Service\"")))
           .andDo(MockMvcRestDocumentation.document("/",
                                                    responseFields(
                                                            fieldWithPath("name").description("The name of the service"),
                                                            fieldWithPath("list").description("A list of Integers"),
                                                            fieldWithPath("calledTimes").description(
                                                                    "A count of the number of times this resource has been called"),
                                                            fieldWithPath("deployEnvironment").description(
                                                                    "The environment the service is deployed to")
                                                    )
                  )
           );
    }
}
```

I'm at a total loss as to what to do here.

When I pause the code with the debugger I can see that the `RestDocumentationContextProvider` passed into the setup method has a value called `outputDirectory` that is null. So it seems to me that it's not picking up the system property for some reason.
If I look in `valuesStore.storedValues` there is one key/value pair with the key `class org.springframework.restdocs.ManualRestDocumentation` and a value that contains (among other things) `outputDirectory` set to `target/generated-snippets`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem's caused by your use of `/` when calling `MockMvcRestDocumentation.document("/")`. The javadoc describes it as "an identifier for the API call that is being documented". The reference documentation [describes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-documentation-snippets-invoking-the-service) how this identifier is used when creating the  names of the snippet files that are generated.

When the identifier starts with `/` it is [already absolute so the configured output directory is ignored](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/blob/f7605a479c08d1d3f2439133c4c70f0e3ba77a0e/spring-restdocs-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/restdocs/snippet/StandardWriterResolver.java#L84-L90). I would recommend using something like `index` or `root` as the identifier instead. This will result in a directory named `index` or `root` being created in the configured output directory. This directory will contain all of the snippets for the API operation that you're documenting.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! It seems obvious now that I know :-D